Error while initializing SparkSession in Windows
I'm getting the below error message while initialing the SparkSession in my Windows system.
I have followed the below steps and added the respective path as Env Varaiable:

Install Java 11 and set JAVA_HOME as env variable
Create a venv and Install Python 3.10 using Anaconda
Download Spark: https://dlcdn.apache.org/spark/spark-3.5.1/spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3.tgz
Set SPARK_HOME as environment variable
Downloaded Hadoop for windows: https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils
Set the HADOOP_HOME environment variable

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
print("Packages Imported...")


def load_dataframe(path):
    
    df = spark.read.format("csv") \
        .option("header", True) \
        .load(path)
        
    return df


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Running app1.py...")
     
    spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .appName("app1") \
        .master("local[3]") \
        .getOrCreate()
    
    # Print spark version
    print("Spark Version: ", spark.version)
    
    # wines_df = load_dataframe("./data/wine.csv")
    
    # print(type(wines_df))                  
    # print(wines_df.printSchema())  


Error Message:


Using winutils on versions of spark higher than 3.1 requires adding the path for the DLL to your windows PATH env.  Also, you should follow the instructions on the winutils page and get the artefacts from https://github.com/cdarlint/winutils instead and make sure they are the correct version.
Alternatively, I'd suggest you look at the option of using bare-naked fs, these instructions explain how to get it working.
